# Javascript Accessor properties confusion

Tags: javascript, properties, accessor

I am not sure why this code gives me an error. All I want to do is create an object that has an array as a property. I want to achieve this with a setter and getter but for some reason when I do `this.array = []` inside the setArray function I get **Maximum call stack size exceeded**. What am I doing wrong ? What am I missing about Javascript's accessor properties.

```
var obj = {
  set array(size) {
   this.array = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
        this.array[i] = i; 
   }
  }
};


var myObj = Object.create(obj); 
myObj.array = 20;
```

Comment: *"...I want to achieve this with a setter and getter..."* What do you want the getter to return? I intentionally stayed away from including one in my answer because if it returns an array, then we have a really strange property that "is" a number when set but an array when gotten. That's usually not ideal... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning to a property with a setter from within the setter, which is why it recurses forever:

```
var obj = {
    set array(size) {                   // <== The property is called `array`
        this.array = [];                // <== This calls the setter
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
            this.array[i] = i;          // <== This would fail because there's no getter
        }
    }
};
```

You have to store the value elsewhere, for instance here we create a private scope and close over a variable:

```js
var obj = (function() {
    var array = [];
    return {
        set array(size) {
            array = [];                // No `this` here
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = i;          // No `this` here
            }
        },
        showArray() {
            console.log(array);
        }
    };
})();
  
var myObj = Object.create(obj); 
myObj.array = 20; 
myObj.showArray();
```

You asked about avoiding the function. You need the function to make the value of the property truly private. But if you don't want to use it for some reason, and you're not that bothered about it being truly private, you can do what Zoltán Tamási did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971807/157247): Use another property on the same object. His answer uses a `_` prefix on the underlying property (e.g., `_array`), which is a *very* common convention in JavaScript for "leave this alone, it's 'private'" even though there are no private properties. The fact is that even in languages with truly private properties (like Java, where they're called instance fields), there's usually some form of powerful reflection mechanism you can use to get around it, so...

If you do that, one thing to consider is whether you want that private property included in JSON if you serialize. If not, just implement `toJSON` as well so you can control which properties are included during serialization:

```js
var obj = {
    _array: [],
    foo: "a value to include in JSON",
    set array(size) {
        this._array = [];          // Note the _
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this._array[i] = i;
        }
    },
    showArray() {
        console.log(this._array);
    },
    toJSON() {
        return {
            // Here we list only the properties we want to have
            // included in the JSON
            foo: this.foo
        };
    }
};
  
var myObj = Object.create(obj); 
myObj.array = 20; 
myObj.showArray();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Comment: Is this possible without the function invocation ? So I can create my object without setting it equal to result of a function ?

Comment: You need the function closure to properly hide the underlying array, or in other words to simulate private member visibility.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: I'm not sure why doing that is a problem? To use the truly private variable above, yes, you need a function. But you could store the array as another property on the object like Zoltán did. The problem with that is it's accessible by any code anywhere. How *much* of a problem that is is up to you, a *lot* of people don't worry about it and go with the "it starts with `_`, leave it alone" convention. If you do that, you probably want the other property to be non-enumerable, though, so it doesn't show up in JSON and such.

Comment: There is no problem. I am trying to learn all of this and it just adds another layer of complexity on top of a concept that I am already not sure about. The struggle goes on :)

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: Ah, I get you. BTW, I'm wrong about the enumerability thing above: Even if you make the other property non-enumerable, it shows up in the result from `JSON.stringify`. I'm very surprised by that. So if it bothered you, you'd have to implement `toJSON` on it and leave that property out.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible to add this through Object.defineProperty(), maybe that will fix the enumerability issue as well ?

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi ... or if you want a clear concept and you are already familiar with higher-level OOP languages (like C#, Java, etc), check out TypeScript. I've been using it for 2 years now with great success. Since that time I feel sorry for all those who (have to) work with pure JavaScript.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Thank you. Typescript does look pretty awesome.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: No, I tried the enumerability thing, still showed up in JSON, that why I went the other way. On TypeScript: It's a style thing, but beware that using TypeScript means you're putting a layer between you and the JavaScript engine. The code that it's running is not the code you wrote, it's a translation of it. A number of TypeScript's features are now available in JavaScript itself, but private variables (and strict typing) are not among them, so there is still a solid use case for TypeScript if you find those things important. If you don't, it's one thing less to learn.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Thank you. I tried the enumerability as well and it didn't work. The strange thing is that if I do `
Object.defineProperty(obj,'_array',{configurable:false,enumerable:false,writable:false});` the writeable has no effect. Not sure if it is because _array is not primitive thus stored by reference or the fact that there is a setter. Typescript is pretty cool but I need to learn Javascript paradigm first, though it can be very annoying at times.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: Those are all the default values for those properties in the descriptor. `Object.defineProperty(obj, "_array", {value: []})` and `Object.defineProperty(obj, "_array", {value: [], enumerable: false, configurable: false, writable: false})` do exactly the same thing. Assigning to `obj._array` definitely won't work. You don't want `writable: false` for what you're doing here, and again, I already checked that making the property non-enumerable has no effect on the JSON output (which is why I showed the `toJSON` thing).

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi: Note that `obj._array` will be read-only (you can't change what's in the property `obj._array`), but the *state* of the array it refers to is still mutable; `obj._array[0] = 42;` works. That's changing the state of the array, not changing the value of the property referring to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder.. Ah man. This is so tricky but I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the setter inside the setter itself when you write `this.array = []`. Introduce another member called for example `_array` and fill that in the setter of the `array` property.

```
var obj = {
  _array: [],
  set array(size) {
   for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){
      this._array[i] = i; 
   }
  }
};


var myObj = Object.create(obj); 
myObj.array = 20;
```

Comment: Using another property somewhat negates the value of using a setter, since a user could access `obj._array`. The closure method of @T.J.Crowder implement information hiding if that's desired.

Comment: You are right, I just pointed out the technical issue without dealing with code semantics. By the way I use TypeScript for years now, and there we have the `private` keyword (my coding convention is to name private members to start with underscore).

Answer (score 0):

You had mentioned that you wanted to use setters and getters, this snippet just uses obj.array instead of showArray to view the object's array.

```js
var obj = (function() {
    var _array = [];
    return {
        get array(){
            return _array;
        },
        set array(size) {
            _array = [];              
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                _array[i] = i;       
            }
        }
    };
})();

obj = Object.create(obj);
obj.array = 20;
console.log(obj.array);
```